# Editor para FPDF

Tags: php, delphi, fpdf

Eu estou procurando um editor FPDF. Alguém sabe algum?

Ou algum link que possa pegar a minha página em PHP e transforme em FPDF.

Preciso criar mais de 20 relatórios de PHP para PDF. Eu sei que a pergunta é genérica, mas não encontro nada do genero.

Enquando não encontro nada eu estou fazendo o meu em Delphi, se alguém quiser ou tiver interesse em me ajudar a fazer.[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]